# Filter sensitive data with VCR issue?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vcr

I'm using VCR to filter the username and password of a client in a project I'm developing right now, but for some dumb reason, the client used the website's domain as the password.

(for example, say I'm trying to log into www.fakewebsite.com, the client set their password to "fakewebsite."  So in the VCR recording, whenever "www.fakewebsite.com" is displayed, it ends up showing "www..COM."  Other than getting the client to change their password, is there a way to filter just when the password is being used and not when it's in a url, or other parts of the recording?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own custom filtering with as much flexibility as you want using VCR's [before_record](https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-6-0/docs/hooks/before-record-hook) and [before_playback](https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-6-0/docs/hooks/before-playback-hook) hooks. For an example, you can see how [VCR itself](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/blob/v2.6.0/lib/vcr/configuration.rb#L218-L231) implements `filter_sensitive_data` in terms of these hooks.